# Does try-catch become irrelevant if Validator is used?

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, exception

I have following code in my ASP.NET calculator project's .aspx.cs -file:

```
    protected void Addition_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            double value1 = double.Parse(Value1.Text);
            double value2 = double.Parse(Value2.Text);

            double result = value1 + value2;

            Result.Text = result.ToString();
        }
        catch (NotFiniteNumberException)
        {
            Result.Text = "Check your input!";
            throw;
        }
    }
```

.aspx -file (messy formatting due to auto-generating code):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CalcForm.aspx.cs" Inherits="task1.CalcForm" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Calculator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CalcStyle.css"/> <!-- Style for calculator app -->
</head>
<body>
    <form id="CalcForm" runat="server"> <!-- Form for the calculator -->
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <!-- Validate first input value -->
        <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Value1" ErrorMessage="Not a number!" Operator="DataTypeCheck" Type="Double">
        </asp:CompareValidator>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <!-- Validate second input value -->
        <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Value2" ErrorMessage="Not a number!" Operator="DataTypeCheck" Type="Double">
        </asp:CompareValidator>
        <br />
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="Value1"  runat="server" ToolTip="Give value 1"></asp:TextBox> <!-- TextBox for value 1 -->
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="Value2"  runat="server" ToolTip="Give value 2"></asp:TextBox> <!-- TextBox for value 2 -->
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; =&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="Result" runat="server" ReadOnly="True" ToolTip="Result"></asp:TextBox> <!-- TextBox for result of the calculation -->
        <br />
        <br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="Addition" runat="server" Text="+" Width="61px" OnClick="Addition_Click" />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="Substraction" runat="server" Text="-" Width="61px" />
        <br />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The values are already validated in the Web Form with CompareValidator -control and if the input is not a number (double), then the CompareValidator will show an error message. But I wanted to try if I could catch an error with the background code that does the calculation.

The catch part should insert "Check your input!" in the TextBox where calculation result normally goes, but there is no reaction if I try to do, for example " 2 + asd ", which should cause an error. Validator does show the message for the second value "asd" since it is not a double value, but the message from the catch-block does not appear.

Am I using wrong Exception here or does the Validator already do the Exception handling and prevent the values from being accessed by the background code?

In short, can I get a second error message to Result.Text from the try-catch block when the CompareValidator already shows it's own message?

Comment: @K4R1 Have you set a break point in your back end code to see if the method is even being triggered when the data is invalid?

Comment: If the Validator catches an error, your try-catch becomes irrelevant. However, your try-catch is not irrelevant as such because it will catch, for instance, an overflow.

Comment: @RyanWilson yeah, I tried breakpoint, but there was no reaction (or then I did the breakpoint thing wrong).

Comment: @K4R1 There's your answer. Breakpoint wasn't hit, it means the Validator error is preventing the form submission.

Comment: @RyanWilson yeah, that was it. I tried to stop at breakpoint with correct values and it did hit when both values were double. So it wont continue with wrong values.

Comment: I tried to use a button which should reset the values, but it did not respond. It seem that when Validator hits an error, it prevents all code execution until the error is no longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I ended up keeping both the try-catch and Validator just in case.